# Touches do not work in cocos2d 3.3 with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to develop a game with **Swift** and **cocos2d**, but my desire was crushed in the very beginning by the touch handling. Is there something special that you need to do when you develop with **cocos2d** and **Swift**?

```
class func scene()->CCScene{
        var scene: AnyObject! = CCScene.node();
        var layer: AnyObject! = MainScene.node();
        scene.addChild(layer as CCNode);
        return scene as CCScene;
    }

    override init(){
        super.init()

        self.userInteractionEnabled = true;

        _background1 = CCSprite(imageNamed:"background2.png");
        _background1.position = ccp(0,0);
        _background1.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

        _background2 = CCSprite(imageNamed:"background2.png");
        _background2.position = ccp(_winSize.width,0);
        _background2.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
        _background2.flipX = true;

        _dynamicBackgroundContainer = CCNode();
        _dynamicBackgroundContainer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_winSize.width*2, _winSize.height);
        _dynamicBackgroundContainer.addChild(_background1);
        _dynamicBackgroundContainer.addChild(_background2);
        self.addChild(_dynamicBackgroundContainer);

    }

    override func touchBegan(touch: CCTouch!, withEvent event: CCTouchEvent!) {
        print("adasd");
    }
```

I have developed many applications with cocos2d and I have never experienced issues with touch handling. Please tell me if you know some workaround.

Comment: try setting the contentSize of self (before enabling user interaction).

Comment: I extended CCScene instead of CCNode and now I directly call the class instead of the static method and it works. I have not tried your method, even though I think it will work. I forgot this small catch to set the node size.